# How to find Yahoo email that does not contain 'facebook' in subject or in message body?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I want to find the messages that do *not* contain the term `facebook` in my Yahoo inbox.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Yahoo search tips](http://help.yahoo.com/tutorials/mmail/mmail/mm_search6.html), you can use the `-` operator to exclude terms: `-facebook`

Comment: I tried `-` syntax but it results in `no message found`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to have a search term to find along with the one you want to 'not find.  So try this...

`a -facebook`

find all messages with the letter **a** in it and without the word **facebook** in.